# can I mix cool water with hot water

Tags: water

My workplace has very hot water and very cool water which is not drinkable. Can I mix both... is it good for health? Are there any ill effects if you drink a hot and cold water mixture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is ill effect if the water contains germs. Boiling water kill the germs, and mixing them with cold water will result in a temperature low enough for the germs from the cold water to survive. That's why in some part of the world, there is some believe not to mix hot and cold water for drinking. It can really cause sickness if the water is not clean.

Reference : 
https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-ill-effects-if-you-drink-a-hot-and-cold-water-mixture

Thus, its better you to take hot water and keep it for sometime and then drink it.

Comment: What about water supplies deemed unsafe due to lead pipes in use and the lead content in the water reaches levels above legal limits?

Answer (score -1):

both hot and cold water comes from the same distilled water can fitted on a water dispenser .Normally a water dispense has both the options.It is true that both the taps give extreme temperatures, one is very cold and and the second is really hot (may be for making tea). Hot water doesn't boil in the dispenser.  Since both are coming from distilled water can, mixing them should not be a issue.

It is always preferable to drink warm water after a meal. It can easily dissolve fats.

Good luck.

Comment: The OP is not necessarily asking about water dispensers.  There are some workplaces where tap water provided has been tested and found not to be safe to be used for drinking water.